# JAX(XLA) vs Numba(LLVM) Reduction

Tags: python, reduce, numba, jit, jax

Is it possible to make CPU only reductions with JAX comparable to Numba in terms of computation time?

The compilers come straight from `conda`:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge numba jax
```

Here is a 1-d NumPy array example

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import jax as jx

@nb.njit
def reduce_1d_njit_serial(x):
    s = 0
    for xi in x:
        s += xi
    return s

@jx.jit
def reduce_1d_jax_serial(x):
    s = 0
    for xi in x:
        s += xi
    return s

N = 2**10
a = np.random.randn(N)
```

Using `timeit` on the following

1. `np.add.reduce(a)` gives `1.99 µs ...`
2. `reduce_1d_njit_serial(a)` gives `1.43 µs ...`
3. `reduce_1d_jax_serial(a).item()` gives `23.5 µs ...`

Note that `jx.numpy.sum(a)` and using `jx.lax.fori_loop` gives comparable (marginally slower) comp. times to `reduce_1d_jax_serial`.

It seems there is a better way to craft the reduction for XLA.

**EDIT**: compile times were not included as a print statement proceeded to check results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When performing these kinds of microbenchmarks with JAX, you have to be careful to ensure you're measuring what you think you're measuring. There are some tips in the [JAX Benchmarking FAQ](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#benchmarking-jax-code). Implementing some of these best practices, I find the following for your benchmarks:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp

# Native jit-compiled XLA sum
jit_sum = jx.jit(jnp.sum)

# Avoid including device transfer cost in the benchmarks
a_jax = jnp.array(a)

# Prevent measuring compilation time
_ = reduce_1d_njit_serial(a)
_ = reduce_1d_jax_serial(a_jax)
_ = jit_sum(a_jax)

%timeit np.add.reduce(a)
# 100000 loops, best of 5: 2.33 µs per loop

%timeit reduce_1d_njit_serial(a)
# 1000000 loops, best of 5: 1.43 µs per loop

%timeit reduce_1d_jax_serial(a_jax).block_until_ready()
# 100000 loops, best of 5: 6.24 µs per loop

%timeit jit_sum(a_jax).block_until_ready()
# 100000 loops, best of 5: 4.37 µs per loop
```

You'll see that for these microbenchmarks, JAX is a few milliseconds slower than both numpy and numba. So does this mean JAX is slow? Yes and no; you'll find a more complete answer to that question in [JAX FAQ: is JAX faster than numpy?](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-jax-faster-than-numpy). The short summary is that this computation is so small that the differences are dominated by Python dispatch time rather than time spent operating on the array. The JAX project has not put much effort into optimizing for Python dispatch of microbenchmarks: it's not all that important in practice because the cost is incurred once per program in JAX, as opposed to once per operation in numpy.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Compile times weren't included above (I called them first in a print statement to check the results). I was expected an O(1) factor, but 10 seemed at bit high - misread `block_until_ready()` to be a `pmap` specific synchronisation call.
Planning to benchmark some recursion dominated loops (fixed-point iteration & time marching), and wanted to make sure my annotations were minimising time in Python.